# Reduce arrays where values are equals

Tags: arrays, laravel, merge, reduce

It's a simple question I think, but i can't handle this.

If you see the image, here is my DB  with multiple Usernames and "instances_id". If I var_dump this I have 11 arrays (and that's normal).
 Is there a way to reduce arrays where "instance_id" is equal?[image: db]

So that I have the first array containing "Alessio,Giorgio", the second one "Alessio,Giovanni" etc.

I use laravel... I hope you can help me

Comment: use groupBy or array_unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use combination of `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT` to retrieve directly from db:

```
$result = DB
    ::table('example')
    ->selectRaw('instance_id, GROUP_CONCAT(Username)')
    ->groupBy('instance_id')
    ->get();
```

Or via laravel collection:

```
$result = DB::table('example')->get();

$result = $result
    ->groupBy('instance_id')
    ->map(function($group){
        $data = $group->first();
        $data->Username = $group->pluck('Username')->implode(',');
        return $data;
    })
    ->values();
```

Comment: The second one worked for me perfectly!! :) Thank you

Comment: 1 question. It returns me the right number of arrays but with keys equals to "instance_id" (so 922, 923, etc).
Is there a way to numerate the keys like 0,1,2, etc?

Comment: @alessiow edited the answer. Use `values()` method. It returns collection items with indexed keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
SELECT * FROM tableName GROUP BY fieldName;
The following query will select all fields along with distinct zip field.
```

Comment: In laravel I use "
 $usersvmmodaltab= DB::table('UsersVM')->select('UsersVM.id','UsersVM.Username','UsersVM.instance_id')->join('Instances','Instances.id','=','UsersVM.instance_id')->groupBy("Instances.id")->get() ->toArray(); and got the error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"

Comment: $result = DB
    ::table('example')
    ->selectRaw('instance_id, GROUP_CONCAT(Username)')
    ->groupBy('instance_id')
    ->get();

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1)select *
from table
group by field1

2) select distinct on field1 *
from table